# multiple sed in for loop with specific input

Tags: bash, sed

I have a for loop with inside two sed commands to edit different files. My problem is the second sed that should edit only the files named aaa but instead I get the error sed cannot edit "not a regular file".

```
for file in $directory 
do [-e  "$file"] || continue
sed -i 's/hello/hello1/g' "$file"
sed -i 's/hallo/hello12/g' [[ "$file" ~ aaa ]]
done
```

Comment: Strange syntax. Which shell do you use?

Comment: Files with names containing `aaa`? Like `for file in *aaa*.*; do sed  -i 's/hello/hello1/g' "$file"; done`?

Comment: that is bash shell

Comment: I dont wanna touch the for loop , only the input of the second sed

Comment: There are too many syntax error here to create a good answer. Probably try http://shellcheck.net/ before asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to replace

```
[-e  "$file"]
```

with

```
[ -e "$file" ]
```

and

```
sed -i 's/hallo/hello12/g' [[ "$file" ~ aaa ]]
```

with

```
[[ "$file" =~ ^aaa$ ]] && sed -i 's/hallo/hello12/g' "$file"
```

Comment: and don't forget the for loop

Comment: @kvantour: What would you correct with this loop? Did I miss something?

Comment: `for file in $directory` is invalid syntax. It should read `for file in "$directory"/*`

Comment: @kvantour: Yes, this is potentially an important hint.